# Error : ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, scons

I'm using scons and ubuntu.
When i when i make some program in using 'scons', there happen error like,

> src/db/DBTextLoader.cc:296:3: error: ‘template class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
>
> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here
>      template class auto_ptr;

and this is my command;

> $ ./configuer
>
> $ source something.sh
>
> $ scons

Actually, I don't have any idea. I'm already searching this site and google. But I didn't find solution.

this is my g++ version (and c++ also was same version.)

> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: What C++ standard version are you passing to G++ (`-std=`)?

Comment: Update to a later version of the package you try to install? One that *doesn't* use obsolete functionality. Or if there's no later version then search for another package that does what you want while still being actively developed.

Comment: @StoryTeller the version is c++11. so I'm input scons evn_file, -std=c++11.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thing my c++ and g++ is already upgrade to a latest version. How can i find package what i need?

Comment: No not the compiler, the package you want to `configure` and use `scons` on. The "program" you have downloaded.

Comment: Likely you can remove the scons tag as the issue is the c++ and not SCons?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you read some books of Scott Meyers, he strongly recommends not to use `auto_ptr`. Actually, new compilers may restrict it's usage because of lots of possible problems with it when using `auto_ptr` in STL containers, etc.

Instead, you should use `std::unique_ptr` if you don't want more that one copy of the object, and `std::shared_ptr` if you need to copy the pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much!. I'm change 'auto_ptr' to 'unique_ptr', at that time my problem solved! Thank you again!